# ReactJs: How to pevent componentDidUpdate to loop more than once

Tags: reactjs

I have seen many example's here with same `loop` error but not able to figure it out for my case.
In my case `props` value will change contineously and I want to log the value only when `previous` props and current props are not same.
But this is looping more than once.
How can I make it run once only.  Any suggestion would be helpful.
Can this will be worked if we use state value ?

**Code**

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  if(this.props.testLog !== '' && this.props.testLog !== prevProps.testLog) {
    console.log("testing done)
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Every time props or state change, your component will update. If you want to prevent that, look into `shouldComponentUpdate`.

Comment: Hi @JanezKuhar thanks for your time. in my case this props value will change very frequently and i have to log the updated value as per change. but here it is logging same log more than twice.

Comment: @Tammy you must be changing state somewhere ...please check that